# Rendering multiple models in DirectX11?

Tags: directx-11

How can I render different geometries before presenting? I have read a lot about the rendering pipeline but I haven't seen any mention of the possibility to configure the pipeline differently for different objects.

My guess is that either 1) the rendering pipeline remembers the depths of the output pixels from the last pass so I can simply reconfigure the bindings and configurations so the parts of the other models that is nearer is visible, or 2) the pipeline is memoryless so some super big buffer that contains all the objects in the scene is needed.

Please give pointers to the keywords I need to look for so I can read more about this. I have read pretty much everything on MSDN but I am not sure I have understood the parts that relate to this.

Comment: Since the render targets and depth buffer are completely under your control you can decide when to render to them, present them or clean them. You can render as many objects as you want and when you want. Configure the pipeline; issue a draw call. Repeat as often as you like.

Comment: Sounds good! I guess this means the rasterizer looks at both the already present depth-buffer values and the fresh ones that comes out of the geometry shader?

Comment: If the depth-check succeeds, the pixel is written to the output, otherwise the pixel is discarded. The values in the depth buffer may have been written in a previous draw call, during this one or directly set by you (for example by clearing it). It really does not matter where the depths came from.